# Nice way (for CPU) to wait for a free lock in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a generic class called "lockingValue" that may be referenced by several threads.  This is to prevent a race condition.

```
class lockingValue(object):
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self._locked=False
        self._value=value

    def _lock(self):
        while self._locked:
            pass
        self._locked = True

    def _unlock(self):
        self._locked = False

    def update(self,val):
        self._lock()
        self._value=val

    def value(self):
        return copy.copy(self._value)
```

What I'm looking for specifically is a nicer way to wait for the lock to become free.  The following is liable to peg the CPU and I would like to avoid it.

```
    def _lock(self):
        while self._locked:
            pass
        self._locked = True
```

**Update:**

I am interested in suggestions and examples of a better & safer design to do this sort of inner-process communication & tracking (tabulating progress across many threads for example).

Comment: This is totally broken and will cause catastrophic race conditions.  Use real mutexes.

Comment: Thanks for the warning Glenn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not wrap your class around Python's own [Lock](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects) object?  Then you don't have to worry about how it's implemented.  It even acts as a context manager, so you can use cute syntax like this:

```
with myLock:
    doSomething()
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`threading.Lock()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Lock).

```
import threading

class lockingValue(object):
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self._value = value

    def _lock(self):
        self._lock.acquire()

    def _unlock(self):
        self._lock.release()

    def update(self, val):
        self._lock()
        self._value = val
        self._unlock()

    def value(self):
        return copy.copy(self._value)
```

As your code stands right now, in your `_lock` method, several threads could be waiting in the while loop, and multiple of them could make it out of the loop simultaneously if the OS thread scheduling conspired against you.

**Edit**

Updated `update` to unlock when finished based on khachik's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Per this and Glenn I'll search deeper for prudent ways to do this.

Comment: the second `update(val)` call will be blocked until someone hasn't called `_unlock()`. `_unlock()` should be called in `update()` (not in this case, but it is better to make a habit to call it in `finally`) or use the with statement, as suggested below.

Comment: @khachik You're right, I wasn't thinking critically enough while redoing the class, thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm thinking that since access to the value must be done through class methods, I'll use the `with` statement and forgo _lock and _unlock methods altogether.   It seems to be the safest and cleanest technique.